# No results with my sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, controller

I would like to find the id of an object in my database. In my controller, I use
`Tag.find_by_name(params[:my_tag])` and it returns nothing, so I try `Tag.where(name: params[:mytag]).pluck(:id)` and still have nothing, but when I try, for example, `Tag.where(name: "Football").pluck(:id)` I have a result so I don't understand. I also try with an SQL query like this one: `Tag.find_by_sql("Select id from tags where name like ?","%#{params[:my-tag]}%")` and I get an error "undefined methode map for string".

In the front-end, I have an AJAX request to handle my choice and to send it to the controller:

```
** $(function(){
        $(".selectable").selectable({
            selected: function(event, ui){
                var selected=$("li[class$='ui-selected']").text();
                $('.bouton7').click(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'Post',
                        url:'../postite',
                        dataType:'script',
                        data:{my_tag:selected}})})}});});
```

In my controller I have this:

```
  def sous_cat
 puts "#{params[:my_tag]}"
@my_result = Tag.where(name: params[:my_tag]).pluck(:id)
puts " My result #{@my_result} "`
```

And the result is this:

```
Football 
(0.0ms)  SELECT "tags"."id" FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = ?                                                   [["name", " Football "]]
My result []
```

Comment: can you print your params?

Comment: Your content needs some formatting!

Comment: Try printing just `puts params[:my_tag].inspect` and tell us the output.

Comment: Thanks I find the solution ,the problem was just to pass all object no juste the name and to get the val of this object thanks for all and sorry to annoying you with this :)